# Selenium/python Finding a specific Text in a table and click button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am working with selenium/python on a web based application which will provide access/removal to doors in my organization.
I am trying to achieve here is to remove specific door from the list of doors which user have permission. so I have to find the specific door text then click on the same line delete button to remove access.

below is the XPath for the text from the table which I got using inspect element
`//*[@id="GrdDeviceListrow1"]/td[3]/label`

`td[]` is changing for row to row

and the button XPath is  `"//td[14]/i"` which is same for the button. please check image

Thanks in advance

[image: Please find the image of table]

I have tried with

`browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()="Outliers"]')`

then find by text, but its not identifying the text, its deleting the button directly.

below is the HTML code I find for the first row value

```
`<label ng-if="(orderByData[$index].type!='dynamicImg' &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type!='dynamicIcon' &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type!='colorpicker' &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type!='tooltipLabel' &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type !='editDelete' &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type != 'dynamicType')" ng-class="{'cursor' : enablerawselectiongrid === 'true' &amp;&amp; !defaulteditmode,'grid-raw-disable' : enablerawselectiongrid === 'false','anchorLinkEffectForLabel':orderByData[$index].underLine == value,'anchorLinkEffect': orderByData[$index].otherCSS == value ,'greenColorText' : orderByData[$index].greenColorText == value,'redColorText' : orderByData[$index].redColorText == value}" class="grid-raw-font mx-input-theme ng-binding ng-scope label-text" ng-hide="((SelectedIndexforedit == data.SrIndex &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type!='' &amp;&amp; isEditClick))||(defaulteditmode &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type=='text'  &amp;&amp; !showcheckboxinedit)||(defaulteditmode &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type=='timepicker')||(defaulteditmode &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type=='checkbox') || (defaulteditmode &amp;&amp; orderByData[$index].type=='twoChk') " type="label">ENZ1-GABIO-GAT-00026</label>`
```

This is the complete code I have used to click all the delete button on the table, but now i have to upgrade to click only selected doors...

```
import pytest
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class TestRemoveAccess():
def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.vars = {}
  
def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
def test_remove_access(self):
    # Read Excel file and extract user codes from the second column
    df = pd.read_excel("user_list.xlsx", usecols=[1])
    user_codes = df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
    
    self.driver.get("http://**********/Login")
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginid").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginid").send_keys("******")
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "pwd").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "pwd").send_keys("*****")
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnlogin").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#Link_7 > img")
    time.sleep(8)
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    time.sleep(8)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    time.sleep(8)
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#Link_7 > img").click()
    time.sleep(8)
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".selectedDiv:nth-child(1) > .cursor").click()
    time.sleep(8)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "autoSearchTxt").click()
    time.sleep(8)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "autoSearchTxt").click()
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,45.33333206176758)")
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,45.33333206176758)")
    
    for user_code in user_codes:
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "autoSearchTxt").clear()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "autoSearchTxt").send_keys(user_code)
        time.sleep(8)
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "autoSearchTxt").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(8)
        self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Devices").click()
        time.sleep(8)
        # Loop until the XPath is not available
        count = 0
        while self.is_element_present(By.XPATH, "//td[14]/i"):
            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[14]/i").click()
            time.sleep(4)
            assert self.driver.switch_to.alert.text == "Record Will be Deleted. Are You Sure?"
            self.driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            time.sleep(5)
            self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fa-save").click()
            time.sleep(4)
            count += 1
            self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fa-pencil").click()
            time.sleep(4)

        print(f"The loop performed {count} times for user {user_code}.")
    
def is_element_present(self, by, locator):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element(by, locator)
        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the table in the text form?

Comment: please add the reproducible code snippet that you've tried with the URL so that others can better provide you with the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the table.

Comment: @Shawn I am a newbie in coding. I just right clicked the element and copied it as HTML outer layer and I pasted it here, please correct me if its wrong

Comment: @AjeetVerma Hi currently I don't have the code, but I have successfully achieved to click all the delete buttons in the table. but sometimes, we have to remove particular doors that's where I got stuck.